# Calling Classic ASP Function when Form Submit Button is clicked

Tags: javascript, function, asp-classic

I am new to web development and I am having difficulties with my assignment and Im hoping you could give me some help:

I have a function inside "functions.asp"

```
function SaveTransaction(StudentID, UserID, TransactionID)
  dim sql
  sql = "EXEC procInsert_Transaction"
  sql = sql & "  @StudentID=" & StudentID
  sql = sql & ", @PostedBy=" & UserID
  sql = sql & ", @TransactionID=" & TransactionID
  cnMain.Execute(sql)
end function
```

And I want to call it when a submit button is clicked inside my "askstudno.asp"

```
<form name="popstud" action="askstudno.asp" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="ref" value="<%=ref%>">
        <!--- variables needed by student_pop.asp --->
        <input type="hidden" name="send" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="studid"> <!--- Student ID --->
            Enter Student No: 
            <span style="vertical-align:middle;">
            <input type="text" name="studno" value="<%=request("studno")%>">
            <input type="submit" value="Go">
            </span>
</form>
```

I know this is a very simple question but please, any help will do. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
<!--#include file="functions.asp"-->
```

To make the your functions available to your askstudno.asp page, and then use Request.Form.  I'm assuming here that your "ref" form field contains the transaction id.  I can't see any form field relating to UserId so I'm also assuming that you have it stored in a session variable.

```
SaveTransaction(Request.Form("studid"),Session("UserId"),Request.Form("ref"))
```

Here's a page with more info on the Request object

http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_ref_request.asp